# update SharePoint managed path

Tags: 2016

I have one site collection created with explicit managed path

http://spsite.com/search

is it possible to change the search to indexer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You have several ways you can do it. In your case probably rename methods will work:

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://spsite.com/search
$uri = New-Object System.Uri("http://spsite.com/indexer")
$site.Rename($uri)
```

(you might need to create that explicit managed path beforehand)

Alternatively, you can use `copy-spSite` cmdlet.

For a full comparison of renaming methods refer to: [SharePoint 2016: Rename Site Collection URL Best Practice](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34032.sharepoint-2016-rename-site-collection-url-best-practice.aspx)